# How to generate Unique Filename everytime a user upload an image using Blob,FileSave,javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, sql, blob, filepath

Here's the thing. I have a filepath in my code behind that sends the image file in SQL database and save the image to a specified folder. Also, I have a customization canvas that allows user to customize and design their order. I am using Blob filesave to save that customized design and my problem is I don't know how to generate a UNIQUE filename since when I upload the same filename, it will update (delete the old file name and replace the recent one) to the folder. Is it possible to generate a unique filename?

## HTML&Script

```
  <input type="button" id="saveImg" value="Save Image"/>
 <script>
        $("#saveImg").click(function(){
            $("#canvas").get(0).toBlob(function(blob){ 
                saveAs(blob, "myImg.png");
               
        });
        });
        </script>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Math.random().toString(36).slice(2) + ext`?

Comment: Personally, I would recommend creating the unique name serverside for security reasons. Don't do it in javascript.

Comment: There should probably be an 'order ID' generated by the server that associates all the related data. Then it's not a matter of "generating a unique file name" - as the Database key for the BLOB is then, for instance `(orderid, filename)`. A "unique filename" is then entirely synthetic, eg. `http://ordersr.us/myorder/12345/resources/theImg.png`. Only when there is no logical namespace (eg. tinyurl) is a "unique filename" of more interest.

Comment: To get really UNIQUE filename you have to consult your database. So this task would be better handled on the server side.You can generate random filename, but then one day your code will generate filename that exists and ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments about doing this server side, or proxying from some other unique id, are probably good advice to consider.

However if you just want a unique string to name a file with,  you can generate a uuid for it. [(I'd use a library)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) . Uniqueness of a uuid is all but a guarantee (needs something like trillions a day for thousands of years to expect a dupliacte).

Comment: Thank you for your response, but how can i install the package in Visual Studio?